# How to remove Top Safe Area in Zstack With ScrollView Image SwiftUI

Tags: image, swiftui, alert, safeareaview

I'm trying to remove top safe area. Is there any way to remove top safe area from top and image?

Code:-

```
struct ContentView22: View {
@State private var showDialog = false
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Image("CentrImg.jpeg")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width:UIScreen.screenWidth,height: 180, alignment: .center)
                    .clipped()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                VStack(alignment:.leading,spacing:25) {
                    Text("Some text")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            showDialog = true
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showDialog,TextAlert(title: "Title",message: "Message") { result in
            print(result as Any)
            if let _ = result {
            } else {
            }
        })
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    .background(Color.red)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
   }
}
```

Alert Control Class:-

```
import SwiftUI

import Combine

public struct TextAlert {
public var title: String // Title of the dialog
public var message: String // Dialog message
public var placeholder: String = "" // Placeholder text for the TextField
public var accept: String = "OK" // The left-most button label
public var cancel: String? = "Cancel" // The optional cancel (right-most) button label
public var secondaryActionTitle: String? = nil // The optional center button label
public var action: (String?) -> Void // Triggers when either of the two buttons closes the dialog
public var secondaryAction: (() -> Void)? = nil // Triggers when the optional center button is tapped
 }
 extension UIAlertController {
convenience init(alert: TextAlert) {
    self.init(title: alert.title, message: alert.message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    addTextField {
        $0.placeholder = alert.placeholder
        $0.returnKeyType = .done
    }
    if let cancel = alert.cancel {
        addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cancel, style: .cancel) { _ in
            alert.action(nil)
        })
    }
    if let secondaryActionTitle = alert.secondaryActionTitle {
        addAction(UIAlertAction(title: secondaryActionTitle, style: .default, handler: { _ in
            alert.secondaryAction?()
        }))
    }
    let textField = self.textFields?.first
    addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alert.accept, style: .default) { _ in
        alert.action(textField?.text)
    })
  }
 }
struct AlertWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
@Binding var isPresented: Bool
let alert: TextAlert
let content: Content

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertWrapper>) -> UIHostingController<Content> {
    UIHostingController(rootView: content)
}

final class Coordinator {
    var alertController: UIAlertController?
    init(_ controller: UIAlertController? = nil) {
        self.alertController = controller
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator()
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIHostingController<Content>, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertWrapper>) {
    uiViewController.rootView = content
    if isPresented && uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
        var alert = self.alert
        alert.action = {
            self.isPresented = false
            self.alert.action($0)
        }
        context.coordinator.alertController = UIAlertController(alert: alert)
        uiViewController.present(context.coordinator.alertController!, animated: true)
    }
    if !isPresented && uiViewController.presentedViewController == context.coordinator.alertController {
        uiViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
      }
    }
  }

 extension View {
public func alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, _ alert: TextAlert) -> some View {
    AlertWrapper(isPresented: isPresented, alert: alert, content: self)
  }
}
```

Output with alert code

[image: Screen Shot]

Output without alert code:-

[image]

Can someone please explain to me how to remove top safe area from image with alert code, I've tried to implement by above but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested your code. I had no problem with your code.

Comment: `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` should be enough. Are you embedding this view in other views?

Comment: @UfukKöşker, okay, but u can see my screen shot in which showing the top space between image and status bar i want to remove it.

Comment: @PhilipBorbon i have tried but the difference between image and status bar not removed by it

Comment: @UfukKöşker   if i remove the alert then its working fine. Is there any way which working fine with alert.

Comment: I will test again.

Comment: I do not understand the alert you are using. There was no problem when I used Alert this way.


.alert(isPresented: $showDialog) {
                Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("Wear sunscreen"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
            }

Comment: @UfukKöşker i updated my question with alert class please check. if its wrong way to display the alert can you please let me know the correct way.

Comment: @UfukKöşker but i need with textfield in the alert.

Comment: Looks like you need to avoid using `UIHostingController`. There's a posted bug in open radar https://openradar.appspot.com/FB8176223 related to this.

Comment: You might need to resort to other options like using [PopupView](https://github.com/exyte/PopupView). You can add any customization to the view like adding a `Textfield` in the popup.

Comment: ok but is there any no option for core code?

Comment: I solved. I am texting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed your Alert code. You can do the same with a much simpler function.

**Value**

```
@State var testText: String = ""
```

**Alert Func**

```
func alertView() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "Test Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (testTextField) in
            testTextField.placeholder = "Test TextField"
        }
        
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (_) in
            self.testText = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
        }
        
        let cancellButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) { (_) in
            
        }
        
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        alert.addAction(cancellButton)
        
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
            
        })
    }
```

**Using:**

```
Text("Some text")
    .onTapGesture {
        alertView()
    }
```